# Acessar VPN usando máquina virtual

Tags: android, android-studio, avd, vpn

Estou tentando acessar uma VPN através de uma AVD android mas sem sucesso. Se eu tento acessa-la através de meu aparelho real consigo sem problemas mas usando a AVD do android studio ou a do genymotion não é possível.
Já procurei mas até o momento não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar nesse caso.

Comment: voce precisa usar uma iso de uma versao do android e instalar ela num maquina virtual, dai voce pode usar como se fosse um device real (teoricamente, ririri), eu tenho uma aqui, me contate inbox e eu te mando por email

Comment: ops, me lembrei do site, pode ir aqui http://www.android-x86.org/ que tem tudo que voce precisa